# Genes and proteins with a significantly inbalanced composition

Tags: dna, proteins, statistics, amino-acids, nucleic-acids

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_genome#Coding_sequences_(protein-coding_genes)), the median size of a protein-coding gene is 26,288 bp which makes it possible (from statistical considerations) that the nucleotides C, G, A, T appear in roughly equal amounts in one strand. But maybe this is wrong so I want to ask:

> Are there and which specific protein-coding genes have a significant inbalance
>   of amounts of C, G, A, T in one strand?

Related to this is the question if there are larger proteins (containing up to 27,000 amino acids as the [titins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein#Biosynthesis) do) with a significant inbalance of amounts of the 20 different amino acids?

Might it be the case that from an inbalance of the gene an inbalance of the protein may follow?

Comment: I don't know about the base usage/(im)balance, but using the transcriptome sequences, that would be relatively easy to check. For amino acid usage, I think there is a bias for evolutionary older proteins (especially mitochondrial ones related to bacteria) to not use certain amino acids as much (mostly the aromatic ones I think)

Comment: Tangential to the topic of protein, but related to the "strandedness" mentioned in your question, is the phenomenon of [GC skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GC_skew) (not to be confused with [GC content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GC-content)).  Differences in strand composition may be explained by [asymmetric mutational pressures](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12372146) between the leading and lagging strands during transcription and replication.